# reinstalling without alot of options

Tags: boot, wine, sd-card, reinstall

I have no top/side bars and terminal wont start from its folder... (Im lucky to have previous installed wine and firefox and have them on my desktop because the only way I can do anything is from there)

I can install windows programs to help me on my quest..I have NO dvd cds to burn...I do however have an SD card and a reader in the computer...the SD card already has Ubuntu on it from previously installing it...how ever I can seem to get the install process to start?...any suggestions? Im stuck...the computer doesnt seem to want to boot from the SD btw, last time i installed i had to use other ways to get it to work i think it said it would resume from the cd after i opened the installer

is there something out there that will just reformat the hard drives for me ? will formating the hard drive cause my sd card to boot? (guessing not)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](http://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out: I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> and typed `sudo apt-get install unity` and Unity came back!